# Apache redirect from ssl subdomain not working

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, https, redirect, subdomain

I am trying to redirect all traffic to https and all subdomains to main domain and can't get it right. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with latest apache2.

I set up virtualhost for port 80 to redirect all traffic to https:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

and setup ssl virtualhost to redirect all subdomains to main domain:

```
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerAdmin admin@example.com
     ServerName example.com
     ServerAlias *.example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/chain.pem

Redirect permanent / https://example.com

</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

Result is as follows:

WORKING http://example.com to https://example.com

WORKING http://anything.example.com to https://example.com

NOT WORKING https://anything.example.com to https://example.com

Question is: how I redirect ssl subdomain to main domain?

Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is unclear what is the question here. Please consider reformulation.

Comment: Done. I am trying redirect ssl subdomain to ssl main domain. And it is not working.

Comment: Are subdomains located on same server?

Comment: yes..................

Comment: Are you using a wildcard SSL certificate? In order to connect with `https`, even to redirect or process your "alias," you have to have a valid SSL certificate for _whatever_ domain the client sends. The SSL handshake takes place _before anything_ in the Apache server is processed. In other words, if you are not using a wildcard SSL certificate, the SSL handshake will fail for  `https://anything.example.com` _before_ the Apache configuration file ever has a chance to process the alias.

Comment: I suspect you are not, because I just found this announcement that [Let's Encrypt will _begin_ issuing wildcard certificates in January 2018](https://letsencrypt.org/2017/07/06/wildcard-certificates-coming-jan-2018.html).

Comment: That's true....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that it appears that [Let's Encrypt will only *begin* issuing wildcard certificates in January 2018](https://letsencrypt.org/2017/07/06/wildcard-certificates-coming-jan-2018.html), and your server setup is earlier, it appears that you are not using a wildcard SSL certificate.

In order to connect with `https`, even to redirect or process your "alias," you have to have a valid SSL certificate for whatever domain the client sends.

The SSL handshake takes place *before anything* in the Apache server is processed. In other words, if you are not using a wildcard SSL certificate, the SSL handshake will fail for `https://anything.example.com` *before* the Apache configuration file ever has a chance to process the alias.

Whatever else may be an issue, this must be corrected before any further diagnosis, if required, can be had. For example, if the desired behavior is that the `https://anything.example.com` be "redirected" to `http://example.com` you will probably have to use a [`mod_rewrite` condition match](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) as the [`RedirectMatch` directive is only matched against the URL-path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch), and the use of `ServerAlias` will create the *necessary* match for handling the initial query, but will not attempt to "rewrite" or "redirect" the query to another desired URL.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, that makes sense. So is there any way with actual release of Let's Encrypt to make every subdomain on http and https to be redirected to https://example.com? Couldn't it be solved via DNS? Or some other way? Or is there some reliable alternative for Let'S Encrypt which supports wildcard certificates? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: _Lot's_ of certificate providers -- all of the major ones -- support wildcard certificates.

Answer (score -1):

Problem cannot be solved with current version of Let's Encrypt. In 2018 they will release new version with wildcard subdomain functionality which is exactly what I need.

Thanks everybody for your effort.